# database cannot update textbox value in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I am doing a update profile in a web application using vb.net. At first I read the database and put the data into the textbox, then i change the data inside the textbox and click the 'update' button. The problem is when i click the button, it won't update the latest value that i typed into the textbox. It will still update the value where i read from database.

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)            Handles Me.Load
    Dim item1 As String = CType(Session.Item("UserAccount"), String)
    txtUsername.Enabled = False

    conn.Open()
    sql1 = "Select * From [Users] WHERE username='" & item1 & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql1, conn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()

    If dr.HasRows Then
        txtUsername.Text = dr.Item("username")
        password = dr.Item("password")
        txtFirstName.Text = dr.Item("firstname")
        txtLastName.Text = dr.Item("lastname")
        txtDob.Text = dr.Item("dob")
        txtEmail.Text = dr.Item("email")
        txtNumber.Text = dr.Item("phone")
        txtAddress.Text = dr.Item("address")
    End If
    dr.Close()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

'above this image is how i read from the database.

```
   Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim errFirstName As Boolean = True
    Dim errLastName As Boolean = True
    Dim errCPassword As Boolean = True
    Dim errNPassword As Boolean = True
    Dim errDob As Boolean = True
    Dim errEmail As Boolean = True
    Dim errNumber As Boolean = True
    Dim errAddress As Boolean = True
    Dim newFName, newLName, newPassword, newAddress, newNumber, newEmail, newDob As String

    If txtFirstName.Text = "" Then
        txtFirstName.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightPink
        lblFirstName.Text = "cannot be empty"
    ElseIf Not Regex.Match(txtFirstName.Text, "^[a-zA-Z_ ]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success Then
```

.
.
.

This is the 'Update' button click.
Here is where i do all the validation for the value in textbox

```
         If errNPassword = False And errCPassword = False And errFirstName = False And            errLastName = False And errDob = False And errEmail = False And errNumber =             False And errAddress = False Then
        conn.Open()
        sql2 = "Update [Users] Set password='" & newPassword & "', firstname='" & newFName & "', lastname='" & newLName & "', dob='" & newDob & "', address='" & newAddress & "', email='" & newEmail & "', phone='" & newNumber & "' WHERE username='" & txtUsername.Text & "'"

        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql2, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        conn.Close()
        Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/index.aspx?"))
    Else
        Dim message As String = "Please correct the error above"
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
        sb.Append("alert('")
        sb.Append(message)
        sb.Append("')};")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
        Exit Sub 'break
    End If
```

This is how i update the value of textbox to my database where the username is match.

Comment: value of txtUsername.Text is same as what you have got from database or you are changing it? you have to use some non editable primary key in where clause of query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is posting back and running the same code, you have to add `If Not IsPostBack` to Page_Load

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)            Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack
    Dim item1 As String = CType(Session.Item("UserAccount"), String)
    txtUsername.Enabled = False

    conn.Open()
    sql1 = "Select * From [Users] WHERE username='" & item1 & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql1, conn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()

    If dr.HasRows Then
        txtUsername.Text = dr.Item("username")
        password = dr.Item("password")
        txtFirstName.Text = dr.Item("firstname")
        txtLastName.Text = dr.Item("lastname")
        txtDob.Text = dr.Item("dob")
        txtEmail.Text = dr.Item("email")
        txtNumber.Text = dr.Item("phone")
        txtAddress.Text = dr.Item("address")
    End If
    dr.Close()
    conn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```